# Graphical Network Manager for Debian (like gnome or kde)

Tags: linux, networking, internet, debian

I am building a Linux computer from scratch. I am using latest Debian version with OpenBox as window manager. I installed Tint2 as taskbar. I would like to have a network manager, not a command line one as it is already pre-installed, but a visual one like the network manager in Gnome or KDE, to be able to configure a mobile network (with a modem stick), broadband connection, wired or wireless, graphically.

I searched a lot for a a network manager but the single one I found is `wicd` which seems not to support mobile network (with a modem stick)(https://screenshots.debian.net/package/wicd).

What is the network manager used by Gnome or KDE and how to install on my Debian (32bit or 64bit) or what other network manager should I install there?

Thanks!

Comment: It's NetworkManager on Ubuntu but it requires Gnome I guess. If you intall it on OpenBox you can show terminal gui using command: nmtui. To install the program type: apt-get install network-manager. To start: /etc/init.d/network-manager start